# Numpy incorrect dot product when filling

Tags: numpy

I am having some trouble with numpy dot product - the product of a rotation matrix & a vector. Please see code. The two lines should give the same result! Where I am storing the result of the calculation should not affect the calculation. Y should be the same as y1 and y2.

```
import numpy
rotMat = numpy.array([[-0.27514947,  0.40168313,  0.87346633], [ 0.87346633, -0.27514947,  0.40168313], [ 0.40168313,  0.87346633, -0.27514947]])
print "Rotation matrix:"
print rotMat
x = [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
X = numpy.array(x)
X.shape = (2, 3)
Y = numpy.array(6*[0])
Y.shape = (2, 3)
print "X", X
print "Y initialised:", Y
Y[0, :] = numpy.dot(rotMat, X[0, :])
Y[1, :] = numpy.dot(rotMat, X[1, :])
print "Filling Y initialised, Y=", Y
print "not filling Y initialised:"
print "y1", numpy.dot(rotMat, X[0, :])
print "y2", numpy.dot(rotMat, X[1, :])
```

Which gives result:

```
Rotation matrix: [[-0.27514947  0.40168313  0.87346633]
 [ 0.87346633 -0.27514947  0.40168313]
 [ 0.40168313  0.87346633 -0.27514947]]
X [[1 0 1]
 [1 1 0]]
Y initialised: [[0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]]
Filling Y initialised, Y= [[0 1 0]
 [0 0 1]]
not filling Y initialised:
y1 [ 0.59831686  1.27514946  0.12653366]
y2 [ 0.12653366  0.59831686  1.27514946]
```

I am using Python 2.7.11, with Numpy 1.10.1

Comment: So, what's the trouble? Explain the issue with more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are filling in `Y` which is of type `int` and therefore converts all values placed into it to `int`.  When initializing `Y`, initialize as `float`.

```
Y = numpy.array(6*[0], float)
```

per @hpaulj's comment:

```
Y = numpy.zeros((6,))
```

will also work because the default `dtype` is `float`

Comment: Indeed. That is annoying. I wish it gave me more notification when it did that.

Comment: Or `np.zeros((6,))`.  `float` is default dtype here.